# Proper way to create custom JS animations in angular 1.3+ with ng-animate

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, ng-animate, velocity.js

I want to use velocity.js in combination with ng-animate to create custom js-animations for my app. I've searched the web and found a lot of answers and tutorials which all refer to old versions of ng-animate, which apparently has changed the API a lot over time.
So right now, this is how my animation looks:

```
app.animation('.lb-fade', function () {
    return {
        addClass: function (element, className) {
            element.velocity({
                opacity: 1
            },{
                duration: 900,
                easing: 'easeInSine'
            });
        }
    };
});
```

I'm using it like this:

```
$animate.addClass(backdrop, 'lb-fade').then(console.log('promise resolved'));
```

This kind of works, but I have two problems:

1. The promise sometimes get's resolved to early (before the animation is finished). It looks like it is happening randomly.
2. How can I pass arguments to the animation? For example i want some of my lb-fade animations to use velocitys delay option. I could either create multiple animations (!DRY) or access the elements scope inside the animation (which seems really hacky to me). Is there a right way to do it?

Does it even make sense to use ng-animate alongside with velocity or should I just create my own functions to hold the animation code?

Comment: Not sure if a typo, but it should be `.then(function() { console.log('promise resolved'); });` or it will resolve immediately.

Comment: @tasseKATT I tried that before, it didn't resolve at all this way. Probably it returned a rejected promise, I didn't test that. 
See my answer for how I solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is more like a workaround, but I wrote my own animator service now instead of using `ngAnimate` now. It uses angulars `$q` for implementing promises. Basically, this is just how ngAnimate does it, but somehow I think it doesn't know when velocity finished animating.

This is my service:

```
.service('animator', function animator($q) {

    this.flyOutRight = function($element) {
        return $q(function(resolve) {
            $element.velocity({
                //css properties to get animated
            }, {
                duration: 200,
                complete: function () {
                    $element.remove();
                    resolve();
                }
            });
        });
    };

    //some more animations

});
```

Usage:

```
animator.flyOutRight($oldImage).then(function(){
    changeImageMutex = false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you found a great workaround for your problem!

I think your original code didn't work since you didn't use the built-in `done` function. it's actually a wrapper for the default promise that `ngAnimate` returns at the end of an animation.

you used the function with the 2nd parameter `className`: `function (element, className)`

I used angular's `ngAnimate` as follows:

```
app.animation('.lb-fade', function () {
return {
    addClass: function (element, doneFn) {
        element.velocity({
        opacity: 1
      },{
        duration: 900,
        complete: doneFn
      });
    }
  };
});
```

This works great for me.
It looks like the `doneFn` is [still part of the api](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) for `ngAnimate`.
Also, if you still want to use `className` (even though it looks like you didn't use it), you can use the function with it like so:

```
function(element, className, doneFn) {}
```